# How to add universal rendering to Angular(2) CLI app

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-universal

A few months ago i got to release my first angular2 app and everything was rainbows and unicorns. However i've come to notice that google cannot read my async content.

Therefore i need to implement the angular-universal rendering in my application. I've tried the quick start at universal.angular.com but i couldnt get it working. (Errors: http://jmp.sh/VIVVfYw)

You can see the full rep here as i made it open source as well: https://gitlab.com/epenance/kuhrefysio

I would very much appreciate any help i can get as it feels like im just hammering my head against the wall here.

Comment: Universal CLI is a fork of the angular CLI, you can find it on npm here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-cli and the repo is here: https://github.com/devCrossNet/angular-cli (if that's enough of an answer let me know and I'll post it as an answer)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however when i try to do anything with ung such as "ung serve" it breaks with the following error: "core_1.Version is not a constructor"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set up Angular cli + Angular universal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41098155/how-to-set-up-angular-cli-angular-universal)