# How can I upgrade an Angular CLI project?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm attempting to upgrade my Angular 2 project from `2.0.0` to `2.4.1`.  I understand that [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) has been adopted since the `2.0.0` release and `2.x.x` releases should be drop-in replacements.  My experience seems to indicate otherwise. Maybe I just don't know what I'm doing, but I have not found this to be straightforward...

### **Attempt 1 - Manual Version Upgrade**

My naive first approach was to manually update my `@angular` dependencies. You can reference my package.json below (update 1).  I made these changes, then did an `npm install` and I got several warnings then got the following error when I tried to do an `ng serve`.

> Cannot read property 'AssetUrl' of undefined

And my warnings...

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.15: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @angular/core@2.4.1 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/core@2.4.1 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.7.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/http@2.4.1 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@0.6.4 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.0.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@0.6.4 requires a peer of @angular/platform-server@2.0.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@0.6.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@1.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/compiler-cli@^2.3.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@1.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/tsc-wrapped@^0.5.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@1.2.1 requires a peer of webpack@^2.1.0-beta.25 but none was installed.
```

So I went down the rabbit hole of trying to fix these warnings, but I don't know how to fix all of them (e.g., @ngtools/webpack) and some of them appear to be in conflict with each other.  So I abandoned the manual approach of updating my Angular 2 version...

**Original package.json**

```javascript
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "build": "ng build",
    "buildProd": "ng build --env=prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-alpha.9-experimental-pizza",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@types/google-libphonenumber": "^7.4.8",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.4.2",
    "apollo-client": "^0.4.22",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^2.0.4",
    "graphql-tag": "^0.1.15",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.16",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.33",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.39",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.16",
    "codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.2",
    "typings": "1.4.0"
  }
}
```

**Update 1 of package.json**

```javascript
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "build": "ng build",
    "buildProd": "ng build --env=prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-alpha.9-experimental-pizza",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@types/google-libphonenumber": "^7.4.8",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.4.2",
    "apollo-client": "^0.4.22",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^2.0.4",
    "graphql-tag": "^0.1.15",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.16",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.33",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.39",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.16",
    "codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.2",
    "typings": "1.4.0"
  }
}
```

### **Attempt 2 - Use npm-check-updates**

Since when I tried to cherry-pick my Angular dependencies for updates, I ended up in a spiderweb of other dependencies that needed to be updated, I next tried to just update everything.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16074029/2860319) I tried the following:

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates
npm-check-updates -u
npm install
```

This went fine, but when I tried `ng serve`, I got the following error:

> ERROR in AppModule is not a NgModule

Using information gathered [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3157), I downgraded my TypeScript version, that error went away, but a new error popped up.

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically.
> Reference to a non-exported function (position 29:10 in the original
> .ts file), resolving symbol restPaths in rest-paths.ts, resolving symbol
> AppModule in app.module.ts,
> resolving symbol AppModule in app.module.ts

I've been fighting my way through these errors, but the fact that I am having so much trouble is raising red flags.

Am I taking the wrong approach?

Note that I have seen some suggestions about updating Angular CLI projects that recommend uninstalling Angular CLI and reinstalling it, then doing an `ng init` and overwriting your configuration files. This didn't work for me because I already had the latest version.

The statement about having the latest angular-cli was incorrect. I had `angular-cli version 1.0.0-beta.16` whereas the latest at the time of this edit is `1.0.0-beta.24`.  Nevertheless, I did try to update my Angular CLI and run `ng init` on my existing project. I notice now that I didn't follow the steps outlined on the Angular CLI GitHub page precisely.  I skipped the `npm install --save-dev angular-cli@latest`, and I blew away all my node_modules instead of using the rm command they outline.*

Answer (score 95, accepted):

> **USEFUL:**
>
> Use the official [Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/) select your current version and the version you wish to upgrade to for the relevant upgrade guide.
> https://update.angular.io/
>
> See GitHub repository [Angular CLI diff](https://github.com/cexbrayat/angular-cli-diff/) for comparing Angular CLI changes.
> https://github.com/cexbrayat/angular-cli-diff/

**UPDATED 26/12/2018:**

Use the official [Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/) mentioned in the useful section above. It provides the most up to date information with links to other resources that may be useful during the upgrade.

**UPDATED 08/05/2018:**

Angular CLI 1.7 introduced `ng update`.

> **ng update**
>
> A new Angular CLI command to help simplify keeping your projects up to date with the latest versions. Packages can define logic which will be applied to your projects to ensure usage of latest features as well as making changes to reduce or eliminate the impact related to breaking changes.
>
> Configuration information for ng update can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/specifications/update.md)

**1.7 to 6 update**

CLI 1.7 does not support an automatic v6 update. Manually install @angular/cli via your package manager, then run the update migration schematic to finish the process.

```
npm install @angular/cli@^6.0.0
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1
```

---

**UPDATED 30/04/2017:**

**1.0 Update**

You should now follow the **[Angular CLI migration guide](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update)**

---

**UPDATED 04/03/2017:**

**RC Update**

You should follow the **[Angular CLI RC migration guide](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-rc-update)**

---

**UPDATED 20/02/2017:**

Please be aware 1.0.0-beta.32 has breaking changes and has removed `ng init and ng update`

The pull request [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/4628) states the following:

> **BREAKING CHANGE:** Removing the ng init & ng update commands because their current implementation causes more problems than it solves.
> Update functionality will return to the CLI, until then manual updates
> of applications will need done.

The angular-cli [CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/ed5f47dc22d5eb4a5d4b4ae2c8f7cb0ec1a999f3/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-1) states the following:

> **BREAKING CHANGES**
>
> - @angular/cli: Removing the ng init & ng update commands because their current implementation causes more problems than it solves. Once
>   RC is released, we won't need to use those to update anymore as the
>   step will be as simple as installing the latest version of the CLI.

---

**UPDATED 17/02/2017:**

Angular-cli has now been added to the NPM @angular package. You should now replace the above command with the following -

**Global package:**

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

**Local project package:**

```
rm -rf node_modules dist # On Windows use rmdir /s /q node_modules dist
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install
ng init
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You should follow the steps from the [README.md](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/README.md#updating-angular-cli) on GitHub for updating angular via the [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli).

Here they are:

**Updating angular-cli**

To update angular-cli to a new version, you must update both the global package and your project's local package.

**Global package:**

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@latest
```

**Local project package:**

```
rm -rf node_modules dist tmp # On Windows use rmdir /s /q node_modules dist tmp
npm install --save-dev angular-cli@latest
npm install
ng init
```

Running `ng init` will check for changes in all the auto-generated files created by ng new and allow you to update yours. You are offered four choices for each changed file: y (overwrite), n (don't overwrite), d (show diff between your file and the updated file) and h (help).

Carefully read the diffs for each code file, and either accept the changes or incorporate them manually after `ng init` finishes.

Comment: This approach that you are suggesting is for updating the angular-cli version whereas I want to update my angular2 version.  Is this ng init process, where files are overwritten, supposed to update my configuration and bump my angular version?

Comment: That is what's needed to update all the packages. Because the angular-cli updates you with the correct versions that they have pre set in that angular-cli version. Also it makes sure you have cleared cache and deleted all modules to make sure you have no problems that are common when updating npm packages. The only reason I say to do it this was is because angular-cli are still updating configuration settings and changing things around with each version. So to get the correct working configuration you need to do it this way and compare the config files and merge the updates parts manually.

Comment: That is the way that's recommended from the angular team.

Comment: Out of all the "answers" I've seen elsewhere, yours is the *only* one to include updating angular-cli for the project, which is what was missing for me.. thanks!

Comment: "The specified command update is invalid. For available options, see `ng help`." - Is `ng update` correct?

Comment: ok thanks, but for @angular/cli: 1.0.0-beta.32.3 [1.0.0-beta.21], it also says "The specified command init is invalid."

Comment: Looking at the changelog they've removed the ng init and ng update.
see here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/4628

Comment: I've updated the answer now with the latest correct info :)

Comment: @JJB thanks for the update!  Was literally right in the middle of upgrading when you posted that update. Gonna upgrade manually now. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe is better to put the last info first so the first thing you read is the latest one.

Comment: @PhoneixS
Yes, I was thinking that when it got a bit long, thanks for your suggestion, I'll reformat it :)

Comment: Looks like the CLI has moved to `@angular/cli@latest` and is no longer `@angular-cli@latest`

Comment: @BenRacicot yes if you read the answer updates you will see I updated the answer with that already.

Comment: for deleting directory in windows it has to be `rmdir node_modules /s /q`

Comment: Excellent answer, I have used it several times... but yet another fix is needed, I'm working on it right now or I'd provide an answer, but since they have removed "ng init" currently creating a new project and copying over _package.json_ seems to be required. Some say you can do "ng new projectname" on an existing project but this seems scary, just in the process of figuring it out right now.

Comment: may want to add running `npm audit fix` afterward.

Answer (score 5):

Just use the built-in feature of Angular CLI

```
ng update
```

to update to the latest version.

Answer (score 4):

[JJB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41403810/how-can-i-upgrade-an-angular-cli-project/41403927#41403927) got me on the right track, but the upgrade didn't go very smoothly.  My process is detailed below.  Hopefully the process becomes easier in the future and JJB's answer can be used or something even more straightforward.

### Solution Details

I have followed the steps captured in JJB's answer to update the angular-cli precisely.  However, after running `npm install` angular-cli was broken.  Even trying to do `ng version` would produce an error.  So I couldn't do the `ng init` command. See error below:

```
ng init
```

Output:

```
core_1.Version is not a constructor
TypeError: core_1.Version is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\_git\my-project\code\src\main\frontend\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\version.js:18:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    ...
```

To be able to use any angular-cli commands, I had to update my package.json file by hand and bump the @angular dependencies to 2.4.1, then do another `npm install`.

After this I was able to do `ng init`.  I updated my configuration files, but none of my app/* files.  When this was done, I was still getting errors.  The first one is detailed below, and the second was the same type of error but in a different file.

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically.
> Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or
> lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 62:9 in the
> original .ts file), resolving  symbol AppModule in
> C:/_git/my-project/code/src/main/frontend/src/app/app.module.ts

This error is tied to the following factory provider in my AppModule

```
{ provide: Http, useFactory:
    (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions, router: Router, navigationService: NavigationService, errorService: ErrorService) => {
    return new HttpRerouteProvider(backend, options, router, navigationService, errorService);
  }, deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Router, NavigationService, ErrorService]
}
```

To address this error, I had use an exported function and made the following change to the provider.

```
    {
      provide: Http,
      useFactory: httpFactory,
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Router, NavigationService, ErrorService]
    }

... // elsewhere in AppModule

export function httpFactory(backend: XHRBackend,
                            options: RequestOptions,
                            router: Router,
                            navigationService: NavigationService,
                            errorService: ErrorService) {
  return new HttpRerouteProvider(backend, options, router, navigationService, errorService);
}
```

### Summary

To summarize what I understand to be the most important details, the following changes were required:

1. Update angular-cli version using the steps detailed in JJB's answer (and on their github page).
2. Updating @angular version by hand, 2.0.0 did not seem to be supported by angular-cli version 1.0.0-beta.24
3. With the assistance of angular-cli and the `ng init` command, I updated my configuration files. I think the critical changes were to angular-cli.json and package.json.  See configuration file changes at the bottom.
4. Make code changes to export functions before I reference them, as captured in the solution details.

### Key Configuration Changes

*angular-cli.json* changes

```javascript
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.16",
    "name": "frontend"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": "assets",
...
```

changed to...

```javascript
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.24",
    "name": "frontend"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
...
```

My *package.json* file looks like this after a manual merge that considers the versions used by ng-init.  Note my angular version is not 2.4.1, but the change I was after was component inheritance which was introduced in 2.3, so I was fine with these versions.  The original package.json is in the question.

```javascript
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "build": "ng build",
    "buildProd": "ng build --env=prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.1",
    "@types/google-libphonenumber": "^7.4.8",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.4.2",
    "apollo-client": "^0.4.22",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^2.0.4",
    "graphql-tag": "^0.1.15",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.33",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.39",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.24",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.0.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3",
    "typings": "1.4.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: does `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` install the latest that includes the beta version?

Comment: @alltej npm install -g @angular/cli@latest will install the latest version of the angular-cli, which is a beta version.  It will not necessarily use the latest version of angular when you are generating or updating your package.json.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation on here http://angularjs.blogspot.co.uk/2017/03/angular-400-now-available.html you 'should' just be able to run...

> npm install @angular/{common,compiler,compiler-cli,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,platform-server,router,animations}@latest typescript@latest --save

I tried it and got a couple of errors due to my zone.js and ngrx/store libraries being older versions.

Updating those to the latest versions `npm install zone.js@latest --save` and `npm install @ngrx/store@latest -save`, then running the angular install again worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
```

Reinstall (with yarn)

```
# npm install --global yarn
yarn global add @angular/cli@latest
ng set --global packageManager=yarn  # This will help ng-cli to use yarn
```

Reinstall (with npm)

```
npm install --global @angular/cli@latest
```

Another way is to not use global install, and add `/node_modules/.bin` folder in the PATH, or use npm scripts. It will be softer to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution that worked for me:**

- Delete **node_modules** and **dist** folder
- (in cmd)>> ng update --all --force
- (in cmd)>> npm install typescript@">=3.4.0 and <3.5.0" --save-dev --save-exact
- (in cmd)>> npm install --save core-js
- Commenting **import 'core-js/es7/reflect';** in **polyfill.ts**
- (in cmd)>> ng serve

Answer (score -1):

To update Angular CLI to a new version, you must update both the global package and your project's local package.

**Global package:**

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

**Local project package:**

```
rm -rf node_modules dist # use rmdir /S/Q node_modules dist in Windows Command Prompt; use rm -r -fo node_modules,dist in Windows PowerShell
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install
```

See the reference https://github.com/angular/angular-cli