# Anglular CLI to use the latest version of Angular

Tags: angular

Angular 4.3 is released recently, I wish to use that.

I am using Angular CLI version 1.1.0 and when i create an app , it uses angular 4.0.0. How to make Angular CLI to use the latest version of Angular ?

Pls guide me.

Regards

Comment: Change @angular versions in package.json . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41403810/how-to-upgrade-angular-2-version-in-angular-cli-project

Comment: As @Skeptor says, simply update your package.json file. More generally, avoid relying on the CLI as your source of truth. The CLI makes many assumptions and your application may outgrow these assumptions. For example, CLI documentation seems to assume you want to load libraries like _jQuery_ as global variables, something you should avoid doing. Also, it obscures many useful features of the underlying bundler, Webpack, that you may wish to use.

Comment: You can run npm outdated to see all dependencies with updated available. Run npm update to update your dependencies.

Comment: Thanks Skeptor and Aluan for the info, will try

Comment: One way is you can use the following commands,first,you uninstall existing angular/cli using 'npm uninstall -g @angular/cli' and then clean cache using 'npm cache clean' then install angular/cli using 'npm install -g @angular/cli'.This installs you the latest angular/cli.