# Angular upgrade issue 2 to 4 (node version is different)

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

While executing the npm start getting the **ERROR in Cannot read property 'getSymbolByModule' of undefined** error, for that checking the node version in cmd by node -v getting `V6.11.1` but while using the ng-v cmd

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.20-4
node: 4.6.1
os: win32 x64
```

What is the issue behind this, not getting anything shows different version of node.

Answer (score 0):

The version 4.6.1 is inside the project node_modules folder.

You are using an old version of angular cli, You should update to @angular/cli

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

For full instructions on the upgrade process you can view my answer here for upgrading angular-cli https://stackoverflow.com/a/41403927/5963307

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your Angular CLI. NOTE: the package has changed from `angular-cli` to `angular/cli`. Also check [this link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update).

After you have updated your dependencies, your project probably won't work. Don't worry, you will find the answers somewhere on stackoverflow.