# Upgrading Angular 2 to Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-cli, upgrade

I am upgrading the angular version from 2 to 6 by following the Angular Update Guide, but after migrating Angular CLI globally and locally, it could not generate the angular.json file. The project includes systemjs.config.js, it did not have angular-cli.json file, nor @angular/cli dependencies in package json. What can be done to solve this?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41403927/3710630

Comment: How big is your project? If it's not really big, save yourself a lot of time and efforts debugging issues by creating a new Angular Project using AngularCLI and cut/pase your src folder. I'd have done that if I were you. You'll have to make a few changes to the angular.json, and package.json file if you're using any third party libraries.

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera the project size is medium, but I think your idea will save a lot of time instead of spending too much time on debugging.

Comment: I'm 100% sure it will.