# Angular cli server-side rendering without ng eject

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, angular-universal, platform-server

According to [this article](https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2017/03/07/server-side-rendering-with-angular-4.aspx), the only way to implement good server-side rendering with Angular 4's platform-server is to set up a custom webpack config after running `ng eject` on an angular cli project.

Maybe this question is naive of me, but is there any way to keep using the default cli webpack config files and also take advantage of server-side rendering?

I am a newb when it comes to webpack, so I prefer not to eject from the cli.

UPDATE:

[This blog post](https://medium.com/@evertonrobertoauler/angular-4-universal-app-with-angular-cli-db8b53bba07d) is a really good resource. However, I am now waiting for the @angular/material library to be compatible with angular universal (It's not yet, but should be coming soon).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set up Angular cli + Angular universal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41098155/how-to-set-up-angular-cli-angular-universal)

Answer (score 0):

Currently Angular-CLI don't support server-side rendering. You can take a look at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1050 for more details. So it is waiting to support for Angular Universal as [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/2749).

Now you can use [Universal-CLI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-cli) that it is fork from Angular-CLI supporting Angular Universal.

Hope this help!